# Div not 100% across

Tags: html, css

I have seen the similar questions on Stackoverflow, I tried their instructions but still it makes no difference. I have done the margin:0 padding:0 on my code too.

The first div is the side bar, the second div is the content(blue), and there is white space on the right. The space on the right isnt a third div, it seems to just be white space. I dont want the white space to be there.

[image: Screenshot]

---

Here is my CSS/HTML:

```css
   #dashboard {
       width: 100%;
   }
   
   #content {
       float: right;
       width: 80%;
       overflow: hidden;
       background: aqua;
   }
   
   #sidebar {
       font-family: "Open Sans";
       font-size: 16px;
       font-style: normal;
       font-variant: normal;
       font-weight: bolder;
       line-height: 18px;
       color: #c5cdd1;
       text-decoration: none;
       background-color: #14253f;
       width: 220px;
       height: 100%;
       float: left;
       width: 20%;
       overflow: hidden;
   }
```

```html
<section id="dashboard">
    <div id="sidebar">
        <!-- Logo -->
        <div id="logo"><img src="img/FDMxLogo.png" /></div>

        <!-- Nav -->
        <nav id="nav">
            <a class="mob-nav"> </a>
            <ul>
                <li id="m-item" class="current">
                    <a href="#"><img src="img/ico_home.png" />DASHBOARD</a>
                </li>
                <li id="m-item">
                    <a href=""><img src="img/ico_report.png" />REPORTS</a>
                </li>
                <li id="m-item">
                    <a href=""><img src="img/ico_cust.png" />CUSTOMIZE</a>
                </li>
                <li id="m-item">
                    <a href=""><img src="img/ico_set.png" />SETTINGS</a>
                </li>
                <li id="m-item">
                    <a href=""><img src="img/ico_about" />ABOUT</a>
                </li>
                <li id="m-item">
                    <a href=""><img src="img/ico_con" />CONTACT</a>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <a href="create.php" class="add">Add Graph<br></a>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <?php echo $div;?>

            <button style="margin-top:0em;width:100%; " type="submit" onClick="remove();">REMOVE</button>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE]

Comment: Post your HTML and all relevant CSS

Comment: where is the html structure?

Comment: Try to remove the width:80% on the content in the CSS.

Can't be of much help without all relevant info.

Comment: Updated with html

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple edit you could try.

I added

```
display:table;
```

to #dashboard.
I removed float from both #content and #sidebar. I also removed thie width percentages from both but left the width:220px. in sidebar.

Then I added

```
display:table-cell;
```

to both #content and #sidebar.

Fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/r5jcv2yu/

Comment: Mind you this works for your simple example and it keeps both the side bar and the content the same height.  Not sure if this is what you want.

Not my usual plan of attack. :P

Answer (score -1):

The 80% width on #content is messing it up I think. You are also using width twice on #sidebar

Comment: Please be sure to reserve any "guesses" for the comments above. If you strongly believe this is the issue, consider editing your question to perhaps include a demonstration, or a bit more information. As it stands, your question is both too assuming and too brief.

Comment: I want the divs to be side by side. Also when I delete it, it has the same width, just below the sidebar.